# Print all tableName for all Datatables in Windbg

Tags: c#, debugging, windbg

I am debugging an ASP.NET web application using Windbg.

I am following this process to print the table name:

```
!dumpheap -type System.Data.DataTable
!do 6bd27818 (DataTable MT)
as !ds .printf "%mu \n", c+
!ds 0bb93b44  (TableName)
```

I am still a newbie to windbg, Is there a script to list all  datatable tablenames? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it Thanks to http://www.infinitec.de/post/2011/08/15/Windbg-Finding-a-specific-instance-of-a-managed-object-in-a-windows-process.aspx

```
.load C:\Program Files\DebugDiag\Exts\psscor2.dll


.foreach(entry {!dumpheap -type System.Data.DataTable -short}){.printf "%p: ", entry; du poi(${entry}+38)+c;.printf "\n"}
```

38 is coming from below:

!do DatatableAddress

```
65675184  40007b2       34 ...ropertyCollection  0 instance 00000000 extendedProperties
0daf0b24  40007b3       **38**        System.String  0 instance 6bbd8de4 tableName
```